# Is it possible to output error on training data through the Experimenter module?

Tags: weka

I am trying to build a learning curve which compares training and testing accuracy versus training set size in WEKA. The testing accuracy portion versus training set size is easily done (through LearningRateProducer), but what I can't figure out is how to get training accuracy results through the experimenter module in an automated way. Here is an example of the output I'm looking for. This result is from the simple CLI module after running IBk.

```
=== Error on training data ===

Correctly Classified Instances        4175              100      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         0                0      %
Kappa statistic                          1     
Mean absolute error                      0.0005
Root mean squared error                  0.0012
Relative absolute error                  0.717  %
Root relative squared error              0.6913 %
Total Number of Instances             4175
```

I could do this through simple CLI, but I have many experiments that I need to generate a learning curve for and I would prefer a less manual way. An experiment module solution would be most desirable.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this information by installing the groovy console and using the following script:

```
data = (new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource("/Path/To/Arff")).getDataSet()
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)

data.randomize(new Random(1))

classifier = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48()

println "|train|\t%acc_{train}\t%acc_{test}"

stepSize = data.numInstances() / 10
for (int i = stepSize; i < data.numInstances(); i += stepSize ) {
    subset = new weka.core.Instances(data, 1, i)
    classifier.buildClassifier(subset)
    evaluationObject = new weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation(subset)
    evaluationObject.evaluateModel(classifier, subset)
    testSubset = new weka.core.Instances(data, i + 1, data.numInstances() - (i + 1))
    evaluationObjectTest = new weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation(subset)
    evaluationObjectTest.evaluateModel(classifier, testSubset)
```

credit to Eibe Frank: https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/How-to-generating-learning-curve-for-training-set-td41654.html

The solution is comparable to Experimenter. You can directly call classifiers through groovy code and batch them however you need.